# Singleton Dispatch not waiting for other groups

Tags: swift, alamofire, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to wait for all my functions from different classes to finish appending data to an array before continueing.

I created a singleton class for the dispath group as such. Rather then it notifying result() when all the groups from the different classes has left, it does it individually.

```
class parralelRunner {
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    result(){
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        print("All functions complete ")
    }
    }
}

class run1 {

    func start(){
        callAPI(){
            filterresult()
        }
    }

    callAPI(completion: (JSON)){
    Alamofire.request("url", headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        if response.result.isSuccess{
            completion(JSON(response.result.value!))
        }else{
            print("Binance - Couldn't import Request: Please check your internet connection")
        }
    }
    }


    func filterresult(){
    parralelRunner.dispatchGroup.enter()
    for .... {

    }
    parralelRunner.dispatchGroup.leave()
    parralelRunner.result()
    }
}



class run2 {

    func start(){
        callAPI(){
            filterresult()
        }
    }

    callAPI(completion: (JSON)){
    Alamofire.request("url", headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        if response.result.isSuccess{
            completion(JSON(response.result.value!))
        }else{
            print("Binance - Couldn't import Request: Please check your internet connection")
        }
    }
    }


    func filterresult(){
    parralelRunner.dispatchGroup.enter()
    for .... {

    }
    parralelRunner.dispatchGroup.leave()
    parralelRunner.result()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `parralelRunner.result()` must only be called once. And there needs to be a call to `enter` at the start of each async process and a corresponding call to `leave` when that is complete.

The first thing you need to do is to refactor `run1` and `run2` to something like this:

```
class run1 {
    func start(){
        parralelRunner.dispatchGroup.enter()
        callAPI(){ JSON in
            if let JSON = JSON {
                filterresult()
            }
            parralelRunner.dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
    }

    callAPI(completion: (JSON?)){
        Alamofire.request("url", headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
            if response.result.isSuccess{
                completion(JSON(response.result.value!))
            }else{
                print("Binance - Couldn't import Request: Please check your internet connection")
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
    }

    func filterresult() {
        for .... {

        }
    }
}
```

Then in whatever uses `run1` and `run2` you need something like:

```
run1.start()
run2.start()
parralelRunner.result()
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but returns nothing.

Comment: What do you mean that nothing returns? Please be clear and specific.

Comment: Please take a look at the edit. This way doesn't work because the functions are being called within a completion block. parralelRunner.result() doesn't wait.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your a king person. Got it working.